# A language engine with no standard library

Tags: syntax, semantics, standard-library

Does anyone know of a language engine (compiler or interpreter, AST, syntax, and basic semantics) but with NO standard library (hopefully not even integers or arithmetic). Is there such a thing? I'd want to be able to implement the standard library in C++. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Maybe. The hope was to have the basic syntax and semantics taken care of, but that I could put in all of the standard libraries myself. If they make it so that something like `#include <iostream>` would fail, that is what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC (and I'm pretty sure a lot of other compilers) lets you build your code without the standard headers and/or libraries, with the `-nostdinc` (also `-nostdinc++` for C++) and `-nostdlib` flags.

For example:

```
$ cat t.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "ouch" << std::endl;
}
$ g++ -nostdinc t.cpp            # Failed compilation
t.cpp:1:20: error: no include path in which to search for iostream
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:5:5: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
t.cpp:5:28: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
$ g++ -nostdinc++ t.cpp          # Failed compilation
t.cpp:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
$ g++ -nostdlib t.cpp            # Compiles, but fails to link
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400158
/tmp/ccPPO3l6.o: In function `main':
t.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
t.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
t.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
t.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))'
/tmp/ccPPO3l6.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
t.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
t.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
t.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
t.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `__cxa_atexit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is used for building things like kernel code that can't use the C library.

<sub>Good luck with implementing a standard library, that's an **enormous** task.</sub>